# Computer won't start after install of Ubuntu

Tags: installation, graphics

I installed Ubuntu and now i get black screen with a blinking line when I start my computer. How do I fix this?

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information. Regards,

Answer (score 2):

### We might need more information.

It would be helpful to know more about your computer (its make and model and the make and model of your video card).

Please open a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and use `sudo lspci -nn | grep VGA`.

What release (i.e., version) of Ubuntu did you install and specifically how did you install it?

You could **edit your question** to provide this information, if the following doesn't enable you to solve your problem.

### But usually, the `nomodeset` boot option fixes this sort of problem.

However, most of the time this problem can be solved by using the `nomodeset` boot option as [explained here in detail](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132).

In summary, on most installed Ubuntu systems (assuming it's the only installed operating system, or it's installed *alongside* Windows or whatever other OSes you run, but not installed with Wubi *inside* Windows), you can enable `nomodeset` by running this command to edit the boot loader's main configuration file:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Then find the line that says this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change it so it says this instead:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

Save the file, quit the text editor, and run this command in a Terminal window:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then reboot, and see if the problem is fixed.